# Header image is overlapping sidebar?

Tags: sidebar, headers

I just changed my header from a background to an image, as that seemed to be the easiest way to link the entire header to my main page (after a whole lot of trial and error with other methods). The one problem is that the image is now overlapping my sidebar instead of the other way around. It's also overlapping some of my menu bar, but it's a part that I can live with or possibly fix myself.

Here's [my site](http://inkandpixelclub.com/) with the header going over the sidebar. How do I get it back under the sidebar like it was before? And now that I think of it, is the whoe header being linked going to cause problems with the various links and buttons in the area where the sidebar overlaps it?

Comment: I'm visiting your site but I can't figure out the problem. Did you remove the header image? I can see the "Search for" form on the sidebar over the header and menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not much of a CSS guru myself, but I think the z-index property might be helpful here. Check this link on Smashing Magazine: [The Z-Index CSS property: A comprehensive look](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/).

Comment: You're more of a CSS guru than you know! It took a little messing around to figure out which position setting would keep my sidebar from wandering to the other side of the page, but once I got that right, z-index worked perfectly!

Comment: And just in case anyone else runs into this problem, I used "Overflow:hidden" on the header to stop it from overlapping my menu bar.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out. "Overflow:hidden" is magical, it always solves all of my CSS problems even though I'm still not very sure of what it does :P

Comment: At least in this case, I have a header image that is slightly larger that the dimensions of my header, so "overflow: hidden" cuts off the parts of the image that don't fit inside of my header space.